# How can we pass the parameters along with block methods in objecitve-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I want to pass the 'NSString' as a parameter for as URLString in below method, how can we do that

```
-(void)makeServiceCallSuccess:(void (^)(NSDictionary *response))success
       failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure {

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:URLString parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    response = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
    success(response);
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", response);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    failure(error);
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

simply add parameter in method, as usually we are doing like

```
-(void)makeServiceCallSuccessWithURLString:(NSString*)urlString withResponseHandler:(void (^)(NSDictionary *response))success
   failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no wat to pass a paramether in that method as it, you can edit it and add a parameter or read a value from aproperty

```
-(void)makeServiceCallSuccess:(void (^)(NSDictionary *response))success
   failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure {

   NSString* myString = self.myProperty;

   AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
   [manager GET:myString parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    response = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
    success(response);
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", response);

 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

     failure(error);
     NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
}
```